# How to get the missing effects on KDEnLive

Tags: linux-mint, kdenlive

I recently installed KDEnLive 4.13.3 on my Linux Mint 17 x64 machine to edit Aerial Movies shot with a GoPro Hero 4. I'd like to use the DeFish effect but can't find it under Effect List:Video:Distort or anywhere else. Is it possible to add it in and if so how? I've checked for any kind of extension adding system but don't see one. Is my system missing a framework I wonder?

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone else is in the same position I was..... It seemed I was missing the "frei0r" effects package which I installed via the Mint Package Manager. Once that was in, KDEnLive gave me a "Lens Correction" effect which, once applied gives you 5 parameters to adjust live (while viewing project monitor) to de-fish or otherwise adjust your images.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This helped! I was facing a similar issue and installing frei0r resolved it. Thank you!

Out of curiosity, how did you manage to find this solution?